# Import properties in multiple changelogs in liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I have some properties which i want to use them in multiple changelog files. For example i have these properties:

```
<property name="blob_type" value="blob" dbms="oracle,mysql"/>
<property name="blob_type" value="bytea" dbms="postgresql"/>
```

Is it possible to define these properties somewhere (e.g. another file) and import it in all of changelog files?

P.S.1. According [this document](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html) it is not possible.

P.S.2. I'm using `liquibase:3.6.2` in a `spring-boot:2.1`. application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to simulate this using [XML includes](http://xml.silmaril.ie/includes.html). Another thing you could try would be to use Liquibase's own `<include>` tag to include a common changelog.

I have not tried either of these methods, so they may not work as expected at all.